# How to print textarea value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to programming, but I have already covered HTML, CSS, basic DOM.

I just want to print that people type like a guestbook. Even though I put some letters on it and click comment, nothing happened. I want to be able to type a message and print it below. How can I do this?

Please let me know if anyone know this problem.

```js
function fn1() {
  var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;
  alert("Thank you!");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /*
  background-image: url(guest.jpg);
  background-size: 450px;
  */
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

.container h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

textarea {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: .5s
}

.btn button {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}

button {
  color: gray;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Visitor comment</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="visitor.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Leave Us a Comment</h2>
    <form>
      <textarea id="text1" placeholder="Add Your Comment"></textarea>
      <div class="btn">
        <button onclick="fn1()" id="btn1">Comment</button>
        <!-- <button>Cancel</button> -->
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <p id="result"></p>
  <script type="visitor.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are already very close. Just append the value of the textbox to your p element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing two things which I will explain to you. If you got any questions feel free to ask them.

First you will have to prevent the form from submitting. For this you can bind a function to the onsubmit event.

Second you have to append the value of the textbox to the result paragraph.

Things like styling etc should be solvable by you. I'm using a list which is not a must.

```js
function fn1() {
  let li = document.createElement("LI");
  let text = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById("text1").value);
  li.appendChild(text)
  document.getElementById("result").appendChild(li);
  alert("Thank you!");

}

function submithandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /*background-image: url(guest.jpg);
    background-size: 450px;*/
}

.container {
  width: 600px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 15px 10px;
}

.container h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

textarea {
  height: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  resize: none;
  outline: none;
  transition: .5s
}

.btn button {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background-color: orange;
}

button {
  color: gray;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Visitor comment</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="visitor.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Leave Us a Comment</h2>
    <form onsubmit="submithandler(event)">
      <textarea id="text1" placeholder="Add Your Comment"></textarea>
      <div class="btn">
        <button onclick="fn1()" id="btn1">Comment</button>
        <!-- <button>Cancel</button> -->
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <ul id="result"></ul>
  <script type="visitor.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much! It work on code snippet but it doesn't work on Chrome. do you know why??

Comment: Check the console for errors (f12). Cant tell you why it doesnt work

Comment: ReferenceError: event is not defined

Comment: Try it again @AbsoluteBeginner

Comment: hmm it says "fn1, submithandler is not defined". it seem like it is fine though. I'll figure it out. thanks to you !!

Answer (score 0):

Another JS solution:

```
var form = document.forms[0];
var textarea = document.getElementById('text1');
var result = document.getElementById('result');

form.onsubmit = () => {
   result.innerHTML = '<li>' + textarea.value + '</li>';
   return false;
}
```

Comment: I've tested it on my pc before posting and it worked. Check out the console log.